# Extension methods to extend class members?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'd like to write an extension method that extends some member of my class.  Specifically, I'd like to extend an enum.  However, this is not working:

```
namespace mynamespace
{
    public class myclass
    {
        public enum ErrorCodes
        {
            Error1, Error2, Error3
        }

        public static double GetDouble(this ErrorCodes ErrorCode)
        {
            return (double)((int)ErrorCode);
        }

        public void myfunc()
        {
            ErrorCodes mycode;
            MessageBox.Show(mycode.GetDouble().ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically, it doesn't recognize GetDouble() as an extension.  This is not just for enums either, I tried creating an extension method for doubles and had the same problem, too.

Comment: How did you even get this to compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only write extension methods in top-level, static, non-generic classes, but they can extend nested classes. Here's a complete example, based on your code:

```
using System;

public static class Extensions
{
    public static double GetDouble(this Outer.ErrorCode code)
    {
        return (double)(int)code;
    }
}

public class Outer
{
    public enum ErrorCode
    {
        Error1, Error2, Error3
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Outer.ErrorCode code = Outer.ErrorCode.Error1;
        Console.WriteLine(code.GetDouble());
    }
}
```

Comment: "Note that it is defined inside a non-nested, non-generic static class"

Comment: @Steven: What are you quoting?

Comment: return (double)(int)code; can be return (int)code, the cast is implicit.

Comment: @Steven: Ah... that wasn't at all obvious without having already followed the link...

Comment: @Yuriy: I know, but in this case I think it actually increases the readability a bit - it reminds the reader of the extra conversion.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Anyhow, +1 for showing a working example instead of just throwing the book at them. You're a kind-hearted AI.

Answer (score 2):

The extension method must be defined in a static class.

See the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

*edit*

As Jon pointed out, the static class must be top-level, not nested.